# A boundary on the size of the set of vertices of a graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

For a connected graph $G$ we define $\nu (G)$ as the maximal size of a set of non-adjacent edges in $G$. We also define $\tau (G)$ as the minimal size of a set of vertices that covers all edges of $G$.
Suppose that $\tau(G)=2\nu(G)$. I need to show that $G$ is a complete graph with an odd number of vertices.
I showed that if there are less than $2\nu(G)+2$ vertices, then $G$ is the required graph. But I cannot explain why there are less than $2\nu(G)+2$ vertices in $G$. Any ideas?

Comment: What a set of disjoint edges is? Matching? Or induced matching? Or something else?

Comment: $\nu(G)$ is the matching number of $G$. A clearer definition: 
A matching in a graph is a set of disjoint edges. The matching number of a graph, $\nu(G)$,  is the maximum size of a matching.

Comment: It is better to say that [matching](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Matching.html) is an independent set of edges, or a set of non-adjacent edges. The word "disjoint " gives some ambiguity.

Comment: "Disjoint" seems perfectly clear to me, since that is just its normal meaning. It is "independent" which is ambiguous since you need to know what the definition of "independent" is in this context. An "independent set of edges" means something very different coming from a matroid perspective, for example.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime "Independent set" and "(non-)adjacent edges" are well-known graph theory terms. Try to google both "Independent set of edges" and "set of disjoint edges" (with quotation marks). I've got 95.8K vs 14.5K result. Anyway matroid perspective is not a part of graph theory.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are missing some conditions, but the given claim is wrong.
Really $2\nu(2K_3) = 4 = \tau(2K_3)$, but $2K_3$ is not a complete graph.

Comment: Is $2K_3$ two not connected copies of $K_3$? I do forgot to mention that $G$ is connected.

Comment: @MasterJ feel free to ask a new question with an updated statement.

Comment: I have edited the question. In the mean while, I think I proved successfuly why the graph has $2k+1$ edges. I showed that there is a cover $\tau$ that is composed of the $2k$ vertices of the $k$ non-adjacent vertices. This implies that there is an additional edge connected to each vertex in the cover. Now I showed that all additional $2k$ vertices are actually the same vertex (otherwise, the matching number is greater than $k$). This implies that there are $2k+1$ vertices, and now it is easier to show that the graph is the complete graph (on an odd number of vertices).